# Query duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table [Employees] and i want to search the duplicate name and view telelephone each department

```
Name    Tel Department
Drew    2134    IT
Jason   34532   IT
Drew    35223   Sales
Jason   12313   Sales
Cruto   32432   IT
John    1234    IT
John    4321    Sales
Rex     5643    Sales
```

how to query this to this output

```
Name    IT Tel NO   Sales Tel NO
Drew     2134          35223
Jason    34532         12313
John     1234          4321
```

Comment: What does your query look like so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT IT.[Name],IT.[Tel] as IT , Sales.[Tel] as Sales FROM
(SELECT [Name], [Tel]
FROM Table1 WHERE [Department] = 'IT') AS IT
INNER JOIN
(SELECT [Name], [Tel]
FROM Table1 WHERE [Department] = 'Sales') AS Sales
ON IT.[Name] = Sales.[Name]
```

**[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0ad52/3)**